# Save image as string in a File using Java

Tags: java

I am using a library which converts html to image and saves image as a file.

Here I don't want image to be saved as a file, rather want it to be in a string which I can process further.

Is there any way I can do that.

Sorry if this question is already asked.

Comment: You could always read the file into a String and then delete it from the file system. Clearly not an ideal solution, but workable in a pinch.

Comment: You want to have image data as a string to process it? Seriously? Why not work with the image data itself?

Comment: What is this library you are using? Is there an option to convert the html to a byte array rather than a file?

Comment: What library are you using anyway?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/ This is the library I am using.

Comment: This library is not maintained at all, If you guys know any better alternatives pls suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **NO!**

I assume Image is a binary format of some sort ... and it will represent the parsed html output as a .jpg and thus has basically merged all layers of the DOM without you being able to reproduce the DOM from the binary representation.

You may want to save `html code` as text and even better as (.html or if need be as .xml) and put that into a file!

**You want to work with Binary!**

If you want Binary in Base64 use the Apache Comons Library for convertion:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

This is the most commonly used Base64 library!

Also check out Apache Commons IOUtils!!

Example Usage here:

```
 Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
```

Comment: Actually I want to binary code of image and then dump it into String using base64 format.

Comment: Why don't you write that in your question?